# Растягивание элементов flex контейнера на всю ширину, используя justify-content: left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

У меня есть flex контейнер Courses. Мне необходимо, чтобы элементы растягивались на всю ширину контейнера и при переходе на новую строку начинались слева. Пробовал justify-content: space-between, но получается что-то по типу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу, чтобы с новой строки они начинались слева и были на всю ширину контейнера. Возможно ли это? Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял: "элементы растягивались на всю ширину контейнера и при переходе на новую строку начинались слева", при этом в верхней строке у Вас четыре элемента, а в нижней два, то вероятно это Вам поможет.

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
    flex: 1 0 25%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  flex: auto;
}

.col {
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

При адаптиве просто меняешь width

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1230px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.items {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}

.item {
  margin: 0 10px 20px;
  width: calc(100% / 4 - 20px);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <ul class='items'>
        <li class='item'></li>
        <li class='item'></li>
        <li class='item'></li>
        <li class='item'></li>
        <li class='item'></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```